# undefined reference to `polyndrom' , `uppercase' and `lowercase'

Tags: c

Why am i getting this error in c:

> lab_6.c:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `polyndrom' ,`uppercase' and `lowercase'

```
include stdio.h 
include stdlib.h 
include string.h 

int polyndrom (char str[]);
int uppercase (char ch);
int lowercase (char ch);
int isNumber (char str[]);
int isReal (char str[]);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    FILE *fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");
    char buf[50];

    //Check whether the file exists or not
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf ("check file name is proper or not\n");

    }

    //Read string
    while (fscanf (fp, "%s", buf) != EOF) {
        //Check if the string is a polyndrom or not
        if (polyndrom (buf) == 1) {
            printf ("String %s is a palindrome\n", buf);
        }
        else {
            printf ("String %s is not a palindrome\n", buf);
        }
        printf ("Its first character is %c\n", buf[0]);
        printf ("Its length is %u\n", strlen (buf));

        int i = 0, countUpper = 0, countLower = 0;
        while (buf[i] != '\0') {
            //check if the character is uppercase or not
            if (uppercase (buf[i]) == 1) {
                countUpper++;
            }
            //check is the character is lowercase or not
            if (lowercase (buf[i]) == 1) {
                countLower++;
            }
            i++;
        }

        printf ("It has %d uppercase letters\n", countUpper);
        printf ("It has %d lowercase letters\n", countLower);
        printf ("\n");

        //check is the string is a real number or not
        if (isReal (buf)) {
            printf ("String %s is a real number. \n\n", buf);
        }
        else {
            printf ("String %s is a interger. \n\n", buf);
        }
    }
}

int polyndron (char str[])
{
    int start = 0;
    int end = strlen (str - 1);

    while (start < end) {
        if (str[start++] != str[end--]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

int uppercas (char ch)
{
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int isRumber (char str[])
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isdigit (str[i]) != '.') {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

int isReal (char str[])
{
    if (strchr (str, '.') != NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have defined polyndron, did you mean polyndrom there?

Comment: Where are `<` and `>` in `include stdio.h`??

Comment: And why one blank line after each line?

Comment: The `uppercas()` and `isRumber()` function names are more typos. There is no `lowercase()` function. These errors should be obvious if you spend a few minutes looking at your own code.

Comment: first problem.  The posted code needs to include the header file `ctype.h`  Second problem: the syntax for including a system header file is `#include <stdio.h>`,  NOT `include stdio.h`  (notice the `<` and the ``>`, notice the leading `#` character

Comment: third problem.  The function name used in the prototype statement must be spelled EXACTLY the same as in the signature for the statement.  I.E. in the prototype: `polyndrom` and in the signature: `polyndron`  Notice one ends with 'm' and the other ends with 'n'

Comment: regarding: `while (fscanf (fp, "%s", buf) != EOF)`  'EOF' is not the only thing that can go wrong.  The best way is to check for success (in this case, ==1.  Also, to avoid a possible buffer overflow and resulting undefined behavior, Always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer when using `%s` and/or `%[...]`.   One less because those input format specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input

Comment: Note: always check the syntax for system functions used;  In this case, the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not a `int`

Comment: regarding: `while (buf[i] != '\0')`  this would be much better written as: `for( int i=0; buf[i]; i++ )`

Comment: because 0 and NULL are evaluated as 'false', this kind of line: `if (uppercase (buf[i]) == 1)`  would be better written as; `if ( uppercase (buf[i]) )

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (`for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line.  2) limit the 'scope' of variables when every reasonable to do so.  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: the header file: `ctype.h` contains the features `islower()`, `isupper()`, `isdigit()`, etc etc so your code could be greatly simplifier by appropriately using that header file.

Comment: regarding: `if (isdigit (str[i]) != '.') {`   the feature: `isdigit()` returns `true` or `false`  It does not return `.`  so this statement is meaningless and will ALWAYS be evaluated as true

Answer (score 0):

Check your spelling. Names must be exact.